# How to add an increasing var +1 if field.tab1=field.tab2 in sql

Tags: sql

If anyone can help
I have two tables like this:

```
field.tab1
111
1110
1111
1112

field.tab2
111
```

I need to update table 2 like this:

```
field.tab2
1113
```

Thank you for your quick response and guidance
Yes I'm new here and in sql, access too, I have those two tables that i need to compare and make the field from second table to have unique records because will be appended to the first table, so this is what i've done in access:

```
SELECT tab2.field, tab1.field, tab1.field1, tab2.field1
FROM tab2 LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab2.field=tab1.field;
```

and manualy increase every tab1.field :) until tab2.field and tab2.field1 become null, where field is the number of client and field1 number of order.

Comment: Please show how you've tried to solve the problem so far yourself, and which part of it you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

The natural answer to this question is:

```
update field.tab2
    set col = 1113
    where col = 111;
```